# Adding missing days of week and time of day in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSGSk.jpg)

Time of Day has levels: Early Morning, Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Late Night

The objective is to make the data uniform by adding missing days of week and time of day between two observations. For instance, if the present row is `Wednesday, Early Morning` and the next row is `Thursday, Morning`, I want to add:

```
Wednesday Morning
Wednesday Afternoon
Wednesday Evening
Wednesday late night
Thursday Early Morning
```

as rows in between.  What I have tried so far is to convert the weeks and day levels into numbers and then subtracting them to come up with how many days or times to add in between. [DataFrame2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENU0Q.jpg)

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to undertake this exercise. Here is the code I have written:

```
for i1, col1 in dfMod.iterrows():
    if col1['day'] == "MONDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 1
    elif col1['day'] == "TUESDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 2
    elif col1['day'] == "WEDNESDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 3
    elif col1['day'] == "THURSDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 4
    elif col1['day'] == "FRIDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 5
    elif col1['day'] == "SATURDAY":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 6
    else:
        dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 7

    if col1['timeType'] == "EARLY MORNING":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'dayIndex'] = 1
    elif col1['timeType'] == "MORNING":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'dayIndex'] = 2
    elif col1['timeType'] == "AFTERNOON":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'dayIndex'] = 3
    elif col1['timeType'] == "EVENING":
        dfMod.ix[i1,'dayIndex'] = 4
    else:
        dfMod.ix[i1,'dayIndex'] = 5
dfMod = dfMod.reset_index(drop= True)
dfMod.leadWeek = dfMod.groupby('adId')['weekIndex'].shift(-1)
dfMod.leadDay = dfMod.groupby('adId')['dayIndex'].shift(-1)
dfMod['diffWeek'] = dfMod['leadWeek'] - dfMod['weekIndex']
dfMod['diffDay'] = dfMod['leadDay'] - dfMod['dayIndex']
dfMod.head()
```

Comment: It is best to show the code you tried, the output you expect, and best yet to add a bit of code as a test DataFrame for us to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve your problem.  This is a class which inherits from `datetime.datetime` and provides some methods for working with your strings to convert to and from a `datetime`.  The advantage of having a datetime, is that you can then use `pandas` various methods associated with same.  In the example I use `resample` to extend your frame and pad it with your desired data.

Another thing that is illustrated here is using `dict` to convert from one thing to another.  This type of structure is generally prefered to the stacked `if`s.

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt

class penta_datetime(dt.datetime):
    """ class which cleaves a day into five pieces """
    pandas_period = '288min'

    part_day = dt.timedelta(minutes=(24 * 60 / 5))
    base_date = dt.datetime.combine(
        dt.date.today(), dt.datetime.min.time()) - dt.timedelta(
        (dt.date.today().weekday() + 1) % 7)

    day_index_offset = {
        "LATE NIGHT": part_day * 0,
        "EARLY MORNING": part_day * 1,
        "MORNING": part_day * 2,
        "AFTERNOON": part_day * 3,
        "EVENING": part_day * 4,
    }

    dow_index = {
        'MONDAY': 1,
        'TUESDAY': 2,
        'WEDNESDAY': 3,
        'THURSDAY': 4,
        'FRIDAY': 5,
        'SATURDAY': 6,
        'SUNDAY': 7,
    }

    @classmethod
    def to_week(cls, date):
        return cls.combine(date, dt.datetime.min.time()) - dt.timedelta(
            (date.weekday() + 1) % 7)

    @classmethod
    def from_strings(cls, dow, tod, week=None):
        if week is None:
            week = cls.now()
        return (cls.to_week(week) +
                dt.timedelta(days=cls.dow_index[dow.upper()]) +
                cls.day_index_offset[tod.upper()])

    @classmethod
    def from_datetime(cls, datetime):
        return cls.combine(datetime.date(), datetime.time())

    @property
    def phase_of_day(self):
        return self.day_offset_index[self.time()]

    @property
    def dow_string(self):
        return self.dow_strings[self.isoweekday()]

penta_datetime.day_offset_index = {
    (penta_datetime.base_date + v).time(): k
    for k, v in penta_datetime.day_index_offset.items()}
penta_datetime.dow_strings = {
    v: k for k, v in penta_datetime.dow_index.items()}
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'WEDNESDAY', 'LATE NIGHT'],
    [1, 'WEDNESDAY', 'EARLY MORNING'],
    [2, 'WEDNESDAY', 'EVENING'],
    [3, 'SATURDAY',  'MORNING'],
    [2, 'SATURDAY',  'AFTERNOON'],
], columns=['ad_id', 'day_of_week', 'time_of_day'])
print(df)

def convert_to_datetime(row):
    return penta_datetime.from_strings(row.day_of_week, row.time_of_day)

# make a copy of the dataframe
ids = df.copy()

# convert the strings into a datetime
ids['ts'] = df.apply(convert_to_datetime, axis=1)

# set the timestamps as the index
ids.set_index(['ts'], inplace=True)

# resample to 5 times a day, and pad the data into the holes
ids = ids.resample(penta_datetime.pandas_period).pad().reset_index()

# (optional) convert the strings to match extended timestamps
ids['time_of_day'] = ids['ts'].apply(
    lambda ts: penta_datetime.from_datetime(ts).phase_of_day)
ids['day_of_week'] = ids['ts'].apply(
    lambda ts: penta_datetime.from_datetime(ts).dow_string)
print(ids)
```

**Results:**

```
   ad_id day_of_week    time_of_day
0      1   WEDNESDAY     LATE NIGHT
1      1   WEDNESDAY  EARLY MORNING
2      2   WEDNESDAY        EVENING
3      3    SATURDAY        MORNING
4      2    SATURDAY      AFTERNOON

                    ts  ad_id day_of_week    time_of_day
0  2017-03-15 00:00:00      1   WEDNESDAY     LATE NIGHT
1  2017-03-15 04:48:00      1   WEDNESDAY  EARLY MORNING
2  2017-03-15 09:36:00      1   WEDNESDAY        MORNING
3  2017-03-15 14:24:00      1   WEDNESDAY      AFTERNOON
4  2017-03-15 19:12:00      2   WEDNESDAY        EVENING
5  2017-03-16 00:00:00      2    THURSDAY     LATE NIGHT
6  2017-03-16 04:48:00      2    THURSDAY  EARLY MORNING
7  2017-03-16 09:36:00      2    THURSDAY        MORNING
8  2017-03-16 14:24:00      2    THURSDAY      AFTERNOON
9  2017-03-16 19:12:00      2    THURSDAY        EVENING
10 2017-03-17 00:00:00      2      FRIDAY     LATE NIGHT
11 2017-03-17 04:48:00      2      FRIDAY  EARLY MORNING
12 2017-03-17 09:36:00      2      FRIDAY        MORNING
13 2017-03-17 14:24:00      2      FRIDAY      AFTERNOON
14 2017-03-17 19:12:00      2      FRIDAY        EVENING
15 2017-03-18 00:00:00      2    SATURDAY     LATE NIGHT
16 2017-03-18 04:48:00      2    SATURDAY  EARLY MORNING
17 2017-03-18 09:36:00      3    SATURDAY        MORNING
18 2017-03-18 14:24:00      2    SATURDAY      AFTERNOON
```

**Note:**

Your weren't terribly clear on how to handle a change in weeks, so that is just stubbed, and left as an exercise for the reader.